# Git doesn't recognize changes using Google drive local directory

Tags: git, google-drive-api

I cloned a project repository into Google drive local directory. 
When I perform changes to the project they are not recognized and cannot be committed.
A strange thing that I noticed (that might be related) is that when the project directory is created in Google drive, automatically a file named "Icon?" is created in the folder. I tried deleting this file and it still didn't work..

I tried cloning the same project to a local directory on my computer and then it recognized the changes I made, hence I believe the problem is with the use of Google drive.
In addition, a colleague of mine cloned the same project to her local Google drive and it worked fine (and she doesn't have the "Icon?" file)..

What can be the problem?

Thanks,
Iris

Comment: I noticed that it works if the git workspace is at the root directory of Google drive (and then it doesn't create the "Icon?" file as well), but doesn't work if it is located under a sub-directory of Google drive.

Answer (score 0):

Set the google drive path and git repo path correctly then your changes should be visible. Also check if you have logged into google drive.